# Why is Minkowski's question mark function denoted by a question mark?

Tags: mathematics

There are some real odd names for functions in mathematics, but [Minkowski's question mark function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question_mark_function), denoted by $?(x)$, may be the oddest one I have ever seen.

In [*Zur Geometrie der Zahlen*](http://ada00.math.uni-bielefeld.de/ICM/ICM1904/Main/icm1904.0164.0173.ocr.pdf), Minkowski doesn't discuss his choice of notation (at least, not in the relevant sections that I could find and use a translator on).

Why is the function denoted by $?(x)$? Most related graphs of it (I've played around with some) fail to show anything like a question mark.

Comment: Previously the factorial function was denoted by ! .  Maybe Minkowski was inspired by that.